# How to browse IIS deployed flask rest api on windows server 2012 r2 from Internet

Tags: python, flask, iis-8, windows-server-2012-r2

I deployed my flask rest api on IIS 8 to windows server 2012 r2. I followed this article. ([https://medium.com/@bilalbayasut/deploying-python-web-app-flask-in-windows-server-iis-using-fastcgi-6c1873ae0ad](https://medium.com/@bilalbayasut/deploying-python-web-app-flask-in-windows-server-iis-using-fastcgi-6c1873ae0ad8)8) I can browse the rest api on the local server but I can not browse the api from other computers on public internet. I can ping the public IP of the server without problem. There is no firewall rule that blocks the server. Would you please help me?

**PS. I am trying to browse by the IP, 185.201.212.219. Is it related to this?**

**edit1: I will try this which is from flask documentation.**

***Externally Visible Server***
If you run the server you will notice that the server is only accessible from your own computer, not from any other in the network. This is the default because in debugging mode a user of the application can execute arbitrary Python code on your computer.
If you have the debugger disabled or trust the users on your network, you can make the server publicly available simply by adding --host=0.0.0.0 to the command line:
flask run --host=0.0.0.0
This tells your operating system to listen on all public IPs.

**edit2: Adding host parameter didn't work.**

Is there any ideas?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What kind of the server? There can be more than one firewall in real world setup. Besides, you also need to review your site bindings on IIS to make sure it can take external traffic, https://docs.jexusmanager.com/tutorials/binding-diagnostics.html

Comment: @LexLi thanks for your reply. If it is due to firewall, how can I ping server IP over internet from client? I put * in my IIS bindigs.

Comment: Ping is over ICMP while web sites use HTTP/HTTPS. Why cannot a firewall allow one protocol while blocking the others?

Comment: @LexLi, how can I check if there is more than windows firewall? Windows firewall is not active.

Comment: I already asked what kind of server it is. Answer that please. A virtual server on AWS/Azure or any other hosting platform at least has one more firewall.

Comment: @LexLi yes it is a virtual server.

Comment: any ideas? @LexLi

Comment: I said clearly "at least one more firewall" is common, so your task is to find out how many firewalls are in fact there in the environment. Talk to the hosting provider or consult a network engineer in your team.

Comment: @LexLi they said there is no other firewall.

Comment: Install tools like Wireshark on both the browser/server machines, and capture network packets on both sides while you reproduce the issue. Then the captured packets should show whether the request from the browser arrives on the server. Not arriving on the server side can prove that either a firewall or other network device blocks the incoming requests.

Comment: @LexLi thanks for your advice.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All ports except 80 was open. When I set port=80, all my troubles seem so far away :)